# Difference in loading font using xelatex or lualatex

Tags: fonts

The code below produces different outputs when using xelatex ou lualatex to compile it

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Pecita}
\begin{document}
test using Pecita font
\end{document}
```

Using lualatex i get:

[image]

Using xelatex i get:

[image]

which is the way it should look.

Does fontspec behaves differently when using xelatex ou lualatex? If yes, what are the differences?

Pecita is a free font that can be obtained from http://pecita.eu/

Ulrike Fischer answer solves part of the "problem". But the use of a different f is still a problem, particularly when used after a j. Using the +aalt feature and lualatex i get

[image: jf_lualatex]

Using xelatex i get

[image: jf_xelatex]

which, again, is the expected result.

Comment: the difference is not so much fontspec, it is the OpenType engine used by XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX; they are certainly not equivalent.

Comment: @will-robertson ok, so this is the expected behavior... in that case, the question doesn't make sense anymore... should i delete it?

Comment: Don't delete it yet -- you may yet receive some more details on why/more specific limitations from someone else (it's late here...)  :)

Comment: You could report to the font authors that the features `aalt, ccmp, mark, rlig` are not documented on their homepage. You could be lucky by trying some languages. Very tedious of course. `\defaultfontfeatures{Language=French}` looks different than `\defaultfontfeatures{Language=English}`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I think that's only because there are some (very few) specific English glyphs in the font. I'd doubt you'd see any differences when comparing other languages besides English.

Comment: But this is a strange font. They've put a lot of effort into creating a lot of different ligatures and contextual glyphs, but they provide no information about how to use them or access them (and if I understand the font correctly, it's an all-or-nothing choice between no alternates or all alternates).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me with lualatex when I activate the +aalt feature (but the f is a bit different):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Pecita}[RawFeature={+aalt}]
\begin{document}
test using Pecita font
\end{document}
```

[image]

But don't ask me, why xelatex uses it directly ...

Comment: that solves part of the "problem", but the use of a different f is still an issue, particularly when used after a j (as in jf). I've updated my question with this issue.

Comment: Where did you find that? Searched everything :-) It is not even in the `fontspec` doc. The doc of Pecita just tells about `calt,liga,locl,smcp,subs,sups` which are all not the desired switches.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I checked the open type features with otfinfo and by looking in the pecita.lua.

Comment: @joãogândara: I tried with context and imho the font isn't working correctly there too. As context is the source for the lualatex fontloader the context maintainers can perhaps tell you what's going on if you ask on the context mailing list (and perhaps they are interested in such a complicated font).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. Very cool. Something nice learned at the end of the week.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok, i'll ask this question on the context mailing list.